# function is not working if I put this into js folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have a add.ctp file, where I can add a multiple rows, and if I put addNumber function to `app/webroot/js`, then its not working, why?

My view file (`add.ctp`)

```
<table id="mytable">
        <tr id="number0" style="display:none;">
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this number')); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid', array ('name'=>'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid][0]')) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another number','onclick'=>'addNumber()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
echo $this->Form->end('Lisa');
?>
```

Adding multiple rows function(`addNumber.js`) is here `app/webroot/js`:

```
var lastRow=0;
function addNumber() { 
$("#mytable tbody>tr#number0").clone(true).attr('id','lisanumbrid'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr#trAdd"); 
$("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeNumber('+lastRow+')'); 
$("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('numbrid','data[Lisanumbrid]['+lastRow+'][lisanumbrid]').attr({'id':'numbridlisaNumber'+lastRow,'name': 'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid]['+ lastRow +']'}); 
lastRow++; 
}
    function removeNumber(x) {
        $("#lisanumbrid"+x).remove();
    }
```

Jquery file is in the same folder like a function, and its echoed in `C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.5.6\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp`

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
```

If I put this addNumber function into `add.ctp` file and put into `add.ctp`
`<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-2.1.1.min.js'));?>` 
then its working nice, put I dont want these into add.ctp file.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Why dont you put all js files inseide webroot/js folder??

Comment: I have all js files inside webroot/js, what do you mean ?

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution. As you found out, it's best to do that in an answer, rather than a question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Added `<?php echo $this->Html->script('addNumber'); ?>` in to `add.ctp` file, after `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling addNumber.js in your add.ctp?
You could call this js file in app\View\Layouts\default.ctp and then

```
echo $this->Html->script(addNumber.js);
```

or you can create a script tag inside add.ctp calling it:

```
$.getScript('/epedidos/app/webroot/js/addNumber.js');
```

By the way, check in your console on firebug (pressing F12 on your keyboard) if the error calling this function is not defined.

Comment: First part, is just a copy form my answer :)

Comment: Hmmm. I guess you were faster than me posting a comment.
But this is it, just add this row in your add.ctp

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all javascript's files used in your view in the working order using script method of Html object in your header section or at the end of your ctp file.

For example:

I will suppose that you have not added jquery and your addnumber before, so at the end of your ctp file:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery','addNumber')); ?>
```

Regard the order, i.e jquery must be before addNumber and both of them must be in `webroot/js/`